# Best Data Access approach for asp.net mvc application with big data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

we have big challenge : Application is too slow because of huge records :(

we look for **best data access pattern** in web application (asp.net mvc 3)

with **big data** (sql server view with more than **66 million records**.)

customers have forms with search fields and will see results within a grid of web page.

since now 
we used both these data access ways:

1-  **entity framework with some features like compiled query**

```
 --get result
 GridModelsResult = VwLoanInquiryList.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
--get count  
 int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);
```

**2- sql server store procedure for pagination and get only current page results**

```
--get result
select t1.* into #t from
(select * 
FROM   VwLoanInquiry
where  CustomerNumber like '%'+@CustomerNumber+'%' 
  ) AS [t1]          
WHERE (@PageIndex=-1 or (t1.ID BETWEEN (@PageIndex-1)* @RecordPerPage AND ((@PageIndex)* @RecordPerPage)-1))
--get count    
select count(*) from #t
```

**3- OLAP; we made cube in analysis services (SSAS)**

but here our problem is to show records with string column type within Cube Cells (its impossible to define Non-numeric fields for measures )

**in additon ,**

to get result faster,our view has index and data types of column has been set .

please help us to know which one of these ways are better ,or if there is an other way what is that?

thanks

Comment: Sounds like a consulting engagement.EF know how, SQL  know how. A code and architecture / business process review to round it off.  try all of your listed options and also consider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853

Comment: Assumed there would be clustered index on VwLoanInquiry table. Second, i suggest use With (Nolock), e.g. From VwLoanInquiry With (Nolock). And there is no any filters applied on #table so there would be no meaning of creating clustered index on your #table, mean to say direct insert into #table is ok here. But instead of #table, refer and use ;With CTE, it may increase performance @ stored procedure option.